# What 'additional Careers features' do you get by completing your profile 100%?

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

When viewing your profile in [Stackoverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) the sidebar states that 'by completing your profile, you can access additional Careers features.' This is followed by pointers on how to complete your profile, for example, adding descriptions to previous jobs, or open source projects you've worked on.

What are the 'additional features' enabled by completing a profile to 100%?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm the developer that worked on this feature.

It's all laid out in the sidebar for each of those "unlockables." The two most notable ones are being discovered by companies (the second unlockable) and qualifying for *Careers Select* (the third unlockable).

- **Get Discovered by Companies** The second unlockable lets you be discoverable by tech companies if you are actively looking for a job or open to hearing about opportunities (no spam - we have a zero tolerance policy for bad recruiter messages).
- **Qualifying for *Careers Select*** The third unlockable qualifies you for special recruiting events where we help you get interview offers from participating companies.

There isn't necessarily one when you fully get to 100%, but we may explore other features that depend on completion.

Comment: Now that I've completed my profile the unlockables aren't listed. I think it would be helpful if the unlockables were listed after completing the profile.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody could you send me a screenshot? jon[at]stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ah, nvm. I was completely overlooking it.

Comment: Does "opt in to get discovered" do anything if I already set my profile to be public?